# PhantomJS 2.0.0 page.open() is no longer working for local file

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have the following javascript file called render.js:

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
system = require('system');

page.onLoadFinished = function () {
    console.log(page.content);
    phantom.exit();
};

page.open(system.args[1]);
```

When I am using PhantomJS 1.9.8 under windows with a local html file I get the right output.

```
phantomjs.exe render.js C:\test.htm
```

When I am using the exact same command with PhantomJS 2.0.0 I am getting a blank page. Maybe a bug in PhantomJS 2.0.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PhantomJS 2 expects URLs that have a protocol, and it misidentifies the `C:` as a protocol to be valid, such as `file:` or `http:`. So you should use

```
page.open("file:///"+system.args[1]);
```

to tell PhantomJS that this is supposed to be a local file.

Valid "URLs" are:

- `file:///C:/test.htm`
- `test.htm` for a file in the same folder

Not valid "URLs" are:

- `C:/test.htm`
- `file:///test.htm` for a file in the same folder

It is always a good idea to check the `status` value and register to error events like `onResourceError`:

```
page.onResourceError = function(resourceError) {
  console.log('Unable to load resource (#' + resourceError.id + 'URL:' + resourceError.url + ')');
  console.log('Error code: ' + resourceError.errorCode + '. Description: ' + resourceError.errorString);
};

page.open(finish, function(status) {
  if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('FAIL to load the address');
    phantom.exit(1);
  } else {
    console.log(page.content);
    phantom.exit();
  }
});
```